# How to synchronize the scrollbars of two differents divs in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I have two divs in my index.html page and i load a different content in each div by selecting the div and injecting the content into it (with jQuery). So I obtain two divs, each div has an horizontal scrollbars to display its content. What I'm trying to do is to synchronize the two scrollbars and if it is possible to have only one scrollbar for the two divs.

Thank you in advance for your answer and sorry if I made mistakes in english because it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: It would be good if you can post some code. this is definitely doable..you need to listen scroll event on both divs and scroll both at the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can obtain the current scroll position using jQuery's scrollLeft() function, described here:
http://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/**

You just set up two scroll listeners that fire each other (be sure to put this in the ready-function of your document!):

```
var div1 = $('#scrollDiv-1');
var div2 = $('#scrollDiv-2');

div1.scroll(function() {
    div2.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});

div2.scroll(function() {
    div1.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

You may put in a time delay using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to save on resources.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried to use this code :

```js
$("#div1").scroll(function () { 
     $("#div2").scrollLeft($("#div1").scrollLeft());
    });
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
     $("#div1").scrollLeft($("#div2").scrollLeft());
    });
```

which worked for a simple example with two divs but i couldn't add this code to my index.html, sorry i can't show the code because it is confidential, but i just have two divs where i put content with a jQuery function, So I don't understand why the code above works in a case and doesn't work in another.